# Method with a static variable that's initialised once (without wrapping in its own class)

Tags: c#, scala, closures

I'm trying to define a method that has some variable "i", such that:

- The code that allocates and initialises "i" is called only **once** (imagine a huge array)
- "i" retains its value with successive method execution
- "i" is only visible inside that method.

This is similar to C++ static variables.

In Scala I can do the following:

```
  val func = {
    println("allocating")
    var i = 0
    () => {
      i += 1
      i
    }
  }

  func()
  func()
  func()
```

I will get:

```
allocating
1
2
3
```

Now, in C#:

Try:

```
Func<int> func = (
    (Func<Func<int>>)( () => {
        Console.WriteLine("allocating");
        int i = 1;
        return ((Func<int>)(() => i++));
    }
    )
)();

Console.WriteLine (func ());
Console.WriteLine (func ());
Console.WriteLine (func ());
```

However, that's extremely ugly.

Is there a better standard way of achieving what I want?

EDIT: Many people posted code to wrap the method in a class. That's not what I'm seeking, I want to have these methods normally in any class without wrapping them in their own classes.
That's why, in the code I posted, I'm wrapping the function I want inside another function that returns it after allocating/initialising some variables.

Answer (score 0):

C# does not support static variables local to a function.

Your description is one of a static member being visible by a single method.

You should consider :

- Having a class static member encapsulated with your function in a class

**Example:**

```
class MyType
{

 static int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

 void foo()
 {
    myArray[i] = ...  // foo is the only method of MyType, hence the only to have ccess
 }
}
```

- Creating a static instance of a Type encapsulating your variable

**Example:**

```
public class Test2
{
    int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
}

public class MyClass
{
    static Test2 instance;  // Only methods of MyClass` will have access to this static instance

    void foo()
    {
        instance.myArray[i] = ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without wrapping the method in a class?

Answer (score 0):

You can design things to behave the way you said by implementing your "static" behavior...

```
public class c1
{
   private static int i = 0; // You might not want it static, look comment after the code

   public int alocating_method() //could be protected
   {
        Console.WriteLine("allocating");
        return ++i;
   }
}

public class c2 : c1
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        c2 p = new c2();
        Console.WriteLine(p.alocating_method());
        Console.WriteLine(p.alocating_method());
    }
}
```

In c2 you can only play with variable i through **alocating_method**...

If you want each instance of c2 to have its own variable i (which I think you probably do), remove the static modifier...